# ¿Porque no me devuelve la imagen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, pillow

Mirad estoy haciendo un código para incluir marcas de agua, pero decidí hacerlo más complejo y me propuse a incorporar también la función de añadir texto no solo la imagen como hice en principio.
Tengo dos funciones, una para añadir el logo y otra para añadir el texto, actualmente me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque da ese error y no se de donde sale, es como si la función que realiza la adición del logo retornara nada. He aquí mi código:

```
# python libraries
import os
import sys
import json
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

logo_default = None
text_default = None


def add_logo(img,logo,ialign):
    # Load size values for JPGuser
    iW, iH = img.size
    # Load size values for logo
    lW, lH = logo.size

    # Start to add the logo:
    if ialign == '0':
        img = img.paste(logo, (40, 20), mask=logo)
    elif ialign == '1':
        img = img.paste(logo, ((iW - lW) - 40, 20), mask=logo)
    elif ialign == '2':
        img = img.paste(logo, (20, (iH - lH) - 40), mask=logo)
    elif ialign == '3':
        img = img.paste(logo, (iW - lW, iH - lH), mask=logo)
    return img

def add_text(img,text,font,textsize,textalign,textclor):
    return img

def watermark(jpguser, imgwater, ialign, text, font, textsize, textalign, textcolor, outputw):
    # JSON ITEM
    item = {}

    item['WMAlign'] = ialign
    item['Text'] = text
    item['Font'] = font
    item['TextSize'] = textsize
    item['TextAlign'] = textalign
    item['TextColor'] = textcolor

    try:
        item['JPGUser'] = jpguser.split("\\")[-1]
        item['PathJPGUser'] = jpguser
        item['WaterMark'] = imgwater.split("\\")[-1]
        item['PathWaterMark'] = imgwater
        item['OutputW'] = outputw.split("\\")[-1]
        item['PathOutputW'] = outputw
        item['Success'] = False

        if os.path.exists(item['PathJPGUser']):

            if os.path.exists(item['PathOutputW']):
                os.remove(item['PathOutputW'])

            img = Image.open(item['PathJPGUser'])
            logo = Image.open(item['PathWaterMark'])

            if imgwater != logo_default:
                img = add_logo(img,logo,ialign)

            if text != text_default:
                img = add_text(img,text,font,textsize,textalign,textclor)

            img.save(item['PathOutputW'])

            item['Success'] = True

        else:
            item['Error'] = "File not exists"

    except OSError as e:
        item['Success'] = False
        item['Error'] = '%s %s %s' % (e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
    except Exception as e:
        item['Success'] = False
        item['Error'] = getattr(e, 'message', str(e))
    finally:
        return item


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i","--jpguser", help="a path that contains the JPG User file")
    parser.add_argument("-w","--imgwater", help="a path a watermark image")
    parser.add_argument("-a","--ialign", help="alignment of watermark image")
    parser.add_argument("-t","--text", help="text will incluide on the image")
    parser.add_argument("-f","--font", help="the font that the text will have")
    parser.add_argument("-ts","--textsize", help="text size")
    parser.add_argument("-ta","--textalign", help="align for the text")
    parser.add_argument("-tc","--textcolor", help="text color")
    parser.add_argument("-o","--outputw", help="output watermark image")
    parser.add_argument("-json", "--json", help="a JSON string with images")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not (args.jpguser or args.json):
        parser.print_help()

    if args.jpguser:
        print(json.dumps(watermark(args.jpguser, args.imgwater, args.ialign, args.text, args.font, args.textsize, args.textalign, args.textcolor, args.outputw)), end='', flush=True)
    else:
        if args.json:
            data=[]
            data_json = json.loads(args.json)
            for i in range(len(data_json)):
                item = watermark(data_json[i]['PathJPGUser'], data_json[i]['PathWaterMark'], data_json[i]['WMAlign'], data_json[i]['Text'], data_json[i]['Font'], data_json[i]['TextSize'], data_json[i]['TextSize'], data_json[i]['TextColor'], data_json[i]['OutputW'])
                item["Id"] = data_json[i]["Id"]
            data.append(item)

            print(json.dumps(data), end='', flush=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

He de decir que lo que quiero hacer es simplemente si en los parámetros de mi bat tengo puesto el logo y la alineación se realice la función de añadir el logo y si no tengo logo y tengo texto que se realicen las dos, a su vez si no hay nada simplemente devuelva la imagen. No es lioso pero no entiendo porque razón la función de añadir logo no me devuelve imagen.

PD: la función de texto todavía no la he incorporado.

---

### Edición

He corregido el primer problema de acuerdo a la respuesta de @FJSevilla, pero ahora al implementar la función para añadir el texto tengo un nuevo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque da ese error ahora solamente por incorporar la función:

```
def add_text(img,text,font,textsize,textalign,textclor):
    iW, iH = img.size
    base = img.convert('RGBA')
    width, height = base.size

    # make a blank image for the text, initialized to transparent text color
    txt = Image.new('RGBA', base.size, (255, 255, 255, 0))

    if font == '0':
        fontfam = 'arial.ttf'
    elif font == '1':
        fontfam = 'verdana.ttf'

    # get a font
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype(fontfam, textsize)
    # get a drawing context
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)

    if textcolor == 'white':
        color = (255, 255, 255, 255)

    # draw text, half opacity
    if textalign == '0':
        d.text((0, 0), text, font=fnt, fill=color)

    img = Image.alpha_composite(base, txt)
    return img
```

He incorporado la función de añadir texto y corregido lo que se me ha indicado pero ahora me tira ese error y no se si es porque he incorporado mal la función o algo similar. Debería de si no le indicamos que añada el logo añadir el texto y si no esta la del texto añadir la del logo o añadir las dos a la vez, pero el caso es que ahora no se porque da error en no atribute split, es como si no recibiera tampoco imagen para editar.

Answer (score 0):

Eso pasa porque el método [`Image.paste()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) realiza la operación sobre la propia imagen cuyo método es llamado, no retorna una nueva imagen. Por lo que cuando haces `img = img.paste(...)`, la variable `img` queda asociada a la salida del método, `None`, y `None` no tiene el método `save` como es lógico.

En vez de hacer

```
img = img.paste(logo, ((iW - lW) - 40, 20), mask=logo)
```

debes hacer simplemente:

```
img.paste(logo, ((iW - lW) - 40, 20), mask=logo)
```

y haz que tu función no retorne nada. Al llamarla, en vez de `img = add_logo(img,logo,ialign)` simplemente haz `add_logo(img,logo,ialign)`, `img` será modificada in-place.

Si no quieres que se modifique la imagen recibida como argumento, debes copiarla primero:

```
def add_logo(img, logo, ialign):

    img = img.copy()

    # Load size values for JPGuser
    iW, iH = img.size
    # Load size values for logo
    lW, lH = logo.size

    # Start to add the logo:
    if ialign == '0':
        img.paste(logo, (40, 20), mask=logo)
    elif ialign == '1':
        img.paste(logo, ((iW - lW) - 40, 20), mask=logo)
    elif ialign == '2':
        img.paste(logo, (20, (iH - lH) - 40), mask=logo)
    elif ialign == '3':
        img.paste(logo, (iW - lW, iH - lH), mask=logo)
    return img
```

Comment: Vale he reparado el sistema con lo que me has comentado pero ahora da un nuevo error. Dejo el código actualizado y el error que me tira.

Comment: Hola Frank, voy a mirarlo a hora. Una cosa, cuando añadas código nuevo, nuevos errores o actualizas en función de alguna respuesta no elimines lo anterior, añádelo como una actualización al final de lo que tienes. En caso contrario la pregunta pierde todo el contexto con las respuestas y comentarios, incluso el título deja de tener sentido, dado que ahora tu error es completamente diferente. La he editado para corregirlo.

Comment: Por otro lado, es mejor que coloques la excepción al completo como texto o al menos que la agregues al completo, mostrando toda la traza y no solo la última línea, suele haber información relevante en ella.

Comment: No te entendi. Pero he mostrado lo que ejecutó al completo y solo se ve el error

Comment: Vale es que estás manejando el error con el try y ocultas la traza... ¿Cómo llamas al script cuando tienes el error?

Comment: Lo llamo mediante un bat, al igual que con la inserción del logo solo que me da el error que he puesto. El try es simplemente para insertar los parámetros y luego ejecutar el código. Simplemente quiero que se ejecuten simultáneamente y que si le añado o no texto coja la imagen que retorna del add_logo o si no le paso comando para ejecutar el add_logo que ejecute simplemente el de añadir texto. No se si me explico

Comment: Porque me resulta extraño que sea incorporar la función para añadir texto y de error, sin embargo si solo dejo el añadir texto si lo hace.